# Unable to unit test simple endpoint with Carter in C Sharp

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, carter

Im trying to unit test my REST web api coded in C Sharp **Carter framework** using **ASP.NET TestHost Version 2.1**
This is my endpoint :

```
namespace Api
{
    public class HealthModule : CarterModule
    {
        public HealthModule()
        {
            Get("/health", async (req, res, routeData) => await res.WriteAsync("I'm healthy!"));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my test :

```
namespace Api.Tests
{
    public class HealthModuleTests
    {
        private HttpResponseMessage response;

        public HealthModuleTests()
        {
            var client = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                    .ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.AddCarter();
                    })
                    .Configure(app => { app.UseCarter(); })
                ).CreateClient();

            response = client.GetAsync("/health").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void HealthRequestOK()
        {
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
            Assert.Equal("I'm healthy!", response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

Note : My app is a NetCore 2.1 app.

Error :

```
Result Message: 
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException : Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What can be causing the above error?

Comment: Technically this looks more like an integration test. That aside. did you check to make sure the state dependencies are referenced by the test project?

Comment: Yes. I checked both the dependencias of my "real" project and the test version. It's the same. And the real one is running fine.

Comment: Also avoid mixing async-await and blocking class like `.Result` which can lead to deadlocks. Make the tests async as well. ie `response = await client.GetAsync("/health")`

Comment: @Nkosi I actually copied from Carter repo itself but nice tip

Comment: Can you include a link to the docs. Want to check versions

Comment: @Nkosi this is the link to testhost : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Nkosi and here the carter sample tests : https://github.com/ritasker/CarterDemos/tree/master/SampleTests